# Случайная фраза из БД

Tags: php

У меня есть случайный вывод фраз на страницу:

```
<?php
//имя сервера
$serverMySql = "localhost";
// логин
$db_log      = "*******";
// пароль
$db_pass     = "*****";
function db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass) //create connection
{
    $r = mysql_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
    return $r;
}
//база данных
$database = "perecc";

//название таблицы в базе
$table = "article";

//кол-во пользователей на странице
$users_on_page = "100";

//подключаемся
db_connect($serverMySql, $db_log, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
// страницы
if (empty($_GET["p"])) {
    $_GET["p"] = "1";
}
$p = $_GET["p"];

// защита от ввода  
$p = intval(isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:1);

// формируем запрос
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `$table`"));

// считаем страницы
$total = ceil($count / $users_on_page);
if ($p > $total) {
    $p = $total;
}

// формируем запрос
$first  = $p * $users_on_page - $users_on_page;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $first, $users_on_page");
?>
<?php
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // цикл вывода
    {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    print "</tr>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$data[0]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[2]</td>";
    print "<td>$data[1]</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Как сделать чтобы у меня выводилась вверху этой же страницы 1 (одна) случайная фраза из БД Таблица "article" столбик "content" при перезагрузке страницы или нажатии на кнопку name="submit" ?

```
<p>Вот здесь Случайная фраза из БД!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>

 <table border="0" width="90%" id="table1">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><form action="http://.......reiting_list.php" method="get" name=""> <input  align="center"  type="image" src="/img/r.png" name="submit"></form></td>

База данных
Фразы: Таблица article

{id} _ _{timestamp}     {content}        {author}
{21}___{2012-10-20}_ {Сейчас котам...} {«Автор»}
```

Comment: А головой подумать не вариант?

Comment: вообще удивительно, вроде вы случайно там и так что-то выводите, так в чем разница-то? другой запрос сделать и в другое место вставить???

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry = 'SELECT `content` FROM `article` LIMIT '.rand(1,$count).', 1;'
```

Google link

Comment: Спасибо всем, особенно KARTOH!